# Why does "of" get converted to multiplication in percentage?

Tags: percentages

Why is $50$% of $500$ equivalent to $\frac {50}{100} × 500$? Why does "of" get converted to "$×$"?

Comment: I ate half "of" your 500 chocolates. How many did I eat? Is it not the same?

Comment: Extending Math Lover's comment, more generally, with respect to the use of the word "**of**" in a mathematical context, compare the two expressions (for example) $[\frac{1}{4} \times 9]$ and [*one fourth of 9*].  In English, by convention, the 2nd expression is interpreted to mean the 1st expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because the $\%$ sign designates a special fraction of something.
I say special because $1\%$ is $1/100$th of something.

In general there are other fractions of course (1/3, 1/5, 1/8, etc.)
but these do not have a dedicated sign as $1/100$ has (the % sign).

And $1/100$th of something (e.g. of $A$) is of course $\frac{1}{100} \cdot A$.

Then $n\%$ means $n/100$ ths of something so it's $\frac{n}{100} \cdot A$.

That's where the multiplication comes from.

Comment: But remember that "of" is ambiguous: $6$ of $24$ pupils wear glasses is $6/24$ of the pupils ...